# JavaScript function not updating value after a while loop

Tags: javascript, scope, amazon-cloudfront

So I'm writing a CloudFront Function that takes the number from a request, calculates the result, and sends it back to the user via a header named "fibval".

The trouble I'm having is primarily within the fibonacci sequence function.
When I test my url doing this: "/fibonacci/13" I'm expecting a custom header to come back with
fibval: 233, however it comes back as fibval: 1.

This is due to my function (code below) not sending the proper number back. Using some hardcoded testing, I've found the issue is primarily with var num2 and return num2. I've validated this by rewriting var num2 to be instantiated to 67, and can confirm that's the issue when I check the header it sends back.

```
function fibFunc(index){
    if (index == 1)
        return 0;
    if (index == 2)
        return 1;
    var num1 = 0;
    var num2 = 1;
    var sum;
    var i = 1;
    while (i < index) {
        sum = num1 + num2;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = sum;
        i += 1;
    }
    return num2;
}
```

I'm no greenhorn to coding, but I'm not super familiar with JavaScript's deeper mechanisms, and it operates differently than expected within CloudFront Functions.

I've attempted to return from within the while loop using something such as

```
while (i < index) {
        sum = num1 + num2;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = sum;
        i += 1;
        if(i == index){
        ``return num2
        }
    }
```

but it returns 503 errors when I put it into practice and try to utilize the function. Similarly, I can not avoid this problem by swapping to the recursive variant of the fibonacci function, as that causes significant performance lag on CloudFront as well as delivers another 503 error.

Due to a comment, I'm providing the handler function to provide more context.

```
async function handler(event) {
    const url = event.request;
    const pathSegments = url.uri.split('/')
    const key = pathSegments[4] //returns fib number from input
    var result = fibFunc(key)
    //var five = 5;
    var response = {
        statusCode: 302,
        statusDescription: 'Found',
        headers: {
        'fibval': {'value': result.toString()},
        //'fibval': {'value': five.toString()},
        }
    };
    return response;
}
```

Comment: 503 errors? doesn't sound like the code you wrote has anything to do with that - though, perhaps the code is causing the server to stop responding I guess - though, there's nothing in the code that's wrong - perhaps you're passing an unexpected value for `index` where you call the function

Comment: When I run your function like so `console.log(fibFunc(13));` the printed result is 233. However, if I run it with 0 like so  `console.log(fibFunc(0));` it returns 1. Based on this, I assume you have a problem extracting `13` from the function URL during your call to `/fibonacci/13`.

Comment: @JaromandaX That's what CloudFront is sending back whenever there's an error. Using an S3 bucket, I can verify that it is a FunctionExecutionError.

Comment: @RAllen I don't believe so, as I can validate that it reads "13" from the URL within the bigger scope of the handler function. I'll update my post to reflect it to provide a larger picture.

Comment: In this line `var result = fibFunc(key)` key is a string and `fibFunc` expects a number. You need to change this line to `var result = fibFunc(parseInt(key))`. My previous assumption was correct.

Comment: @RAllen I've implemented this change, and I still see the error where the header returns "1". I know for sure that the offending line is "var num2 = 1" as manipulating the "1" to be something like "67" will have the header return "67". 

Using the internal testing mechanism CloudFront offers, it does return the expected output, in the case of "13", 233.

Comment: I've saved your `fibFunc` into a JS file and ran it with different input values, and it behaves correctly. Your problem is with the input value. For example, you don't have 5 sections of the URL, so `pathSegments[4]` returns undefined. This is not a problem with `fibFunc` because it returns 233 when executed separately.

Comment: Try to change your response like so `'fibval': {'value': key},` to see what key is equal to during the call.

Comment: @RAllen

I run the test off this URL: http://<cloudfront distro URL>/fib/13

When splitting based off of "/", it splits into this group, copied with a minor change from console.log(pathSegments): 
['https:','<blank in between double slash>' ,'<URL>','fibonacci','13'].

Additionally, using console.log(key), i can verify that it is picking up 13.

Comment: According to [this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/functions-event-structure.html), the `uri` property of the `Request` object is the *relative* path. I think it doesn't contain "http://"

Comment: @qrsngky that was spot on. Using pathSegments[2], while failing me within the CloudFront internal testing system, returns the proper value.

Comment: That means the testing system does not fulfil the specifications. Is there an official "CloudFront internal testing system" that you can run locally?